# Show that in any metric space $(E; d)$, $cl(\{ y \in E: d(x, y) < \epsilon\}) \subseteq \{y \in E: d(x; y)\leq \epsilon\}$

Tags: analysis

However, give an example where, $cl(\{ y \in E: d(x, y) < \epsilon\})  \neq \{y \in E: d(x; y)\leq \epsilon\}$. I'm completely stuck here and I don't know where to start from.

Comment: I think you may have mistyped the question, because the statement in the title of your post is false. Consider $B = \{y\in\mathbb{R}^2: d(0,y)<1\}$. Then ${\rm cl}(B) = B\cup S^1$, both the open disk *and* unit circle, which is obviously not contained in just the open disk.

Comment: Replace $<$ by $\leqslant$, once in the title and once in the body.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I've made the change

Answer (score 1):

Here's one strategy for the proof: let $\overline{B}(x,r) = \{y\in E: d(x,y)\leq r\}$ be the closed ball of radius $r$, and $B(x, r) = \{y\in E: d(x,y)<r\}$ be the open ball of radius $r$. It will suffice to show that $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is closed, since it's a general face that if $S\subset T$ and $T$ is closed, then $\overline{S}\subset T$ (taking closure preserves inclusions, and the closure of a closed set is itself).

For fixed $x,r$, we show that $E\setminus \overline{B}(x,r)$ is open. Take $y\in E\setminus \overline{B}(x,r)$ and put $\epsilon = d(x,y)-r>0$. Then if $d(y,z)<\epsilon$, we have by reverse triangle inequality
$$d(x,z)\geq d(x,y)-d(y,z) > d(x,y)-\epsilon = r.$$
This proves that $B(y,\epsilon)\subset E\setminus \overline{B}(x,r)$. Since the complement is open, $\overline{B}(x,r)$ is closed. By my argument above, this completes the proof.

For an example where $\overline{B(x,r)} \neq \overline{B}(x,r)$, try playing around with the discrete metric:
$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if $x=y$}\\ 1 &\text{if $x\neq y$.}\end{cases}$$.